# Submitting with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I used to be able to submit form data with:

```
submit: (event, view) ->
  @get('store').commit()
```

Now, after updating to Ember Data 1.0.0beta2, I get this error:

```
this.get('store').commit is not a function
```

I'm having trouble finding documentation about the new syntax to use here. Does anyone know how to handle this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ED Beta 2 ou will have to save models directly, by calling either `.save()` or `this.get('model').save()`

Comment: Thanks, Chopper! This works like a charm. I'm curious how you knew this? I searched for a long time trying to find the right approach. The Ember.js documentation seems lacking when it comes to Ember Data, and Ember Data's Github doesn't give any examples. Is there a better source of documentation out there?

Comment: This (as well as a bunch of other useful information on migrating to ED Beta 2) is outlined in [Transition](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) on the ED GitHub page. Some people also put together an overview of their experiences migrating their code on discuss.ember.com

Comment: Thanks again, Chopper. That helps alot.